# Extract a zip file in python [zip file contains .img file in it, and zipfile gets stuck]

Tags: python, zip, unzip, python-zipfile

I am trying to extract a .zip file using python. I am doing it as:

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name)
for f in z.namelist():
    print f
    if f.endswith('/'):
        os.makedirs(f)
    else:
        z.extract(f)
```

This works fine until the .img file is encountered. Once .img is encountered the extract freezes!

How to resolve this?

Comment: As Ashish has noted you have an indentation error on line 4...

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl I typed the code in here, so I missed the indentation part a bit. I have executed the code with a test zip file, with no .img file, it works fine. Only when it encounters .img file it freezes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name)
z.extractall()
```

Comment: Hmm. Try setting zipfile.debug = 3  http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.debug

Comment: I don't know what was wrong! But after a while I got irritated an I shutdown my system. Next time I tried, same code as you have mentioned worked!